# How do I scroll down a scrollable container in Codename one?

Tags: scroll, codenameone

I have a Container element in Codename one and I have set it scrollable. How do I scroll to its bottom from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [scrollComponentToVisible](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Container.html#scrollComponentToVisible-com.codename1.ui.Component-) on the last component. E.g.:

```
myScrollable.scrollComponentToVisible(myLastCmp);
```

Comment: This doesnt do anything for me, any ideas why ? Im adding SplanLabels to a BoxLayoutY container, but it doesnt scroll.

Comment: You are invoking this before the form is laid out/shown